# Touchpad and mouse problems on Zorin OS 16

Tags: mouse, touchpad, zorin

I had problems that originated in Windows 10,
where an update was installed without my permission. 
After it was done, my Dell touchpad would not function correctly
(could click on some things but not others)
and my mouse plugin would exit out of folders/webpages with the left click while sometimes still working as normal.

Now I thought this problem would be fixed by removing Windows entirely
and installing Linux, but I guess that is not the case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to terminal.
- Type in: `sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.
- Type in your password.
- Let it run.

Test to see if it's still malfunctioning. 
If it is, it may be a hardware issue.

Comment: How does the user “Test to see if it's still malfunctioning”?  … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You need to tell the user how to test. Edit your answer to include that.